# How to generate an Tablix programatically in RDLC Report using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I can do it in design but i want to do via program please help in this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48927759/edit) and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see **[ask]**.

Comment: Yeah ! Well Said ! I don't need the exact code please suggest me some idea or how to do it that's it ! Thanks in advance!